# How can I simplify this Rails 3 controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

I currently have this method in a controller:

```
def show
  property = Property.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => property.to_xml(:except => [:address1, :address2, :analysis_date, :analysis_date_2, ...]) }
    format.json { render :json => property.to_json(:except => [:address1, :address2, :analysis_date, :analysis_date_2, ...]) }
  end
end
```

It seems like I can refactor this code to use respond_with, but I am not sure how to customize the output. Do I need to override the as_json and to_xml methods in order to customize the returned data? If I override these methods, will property associations still be handled correctly? For example, a property has many tenants and many contractors. I may need to return those elements as well.

I would assume the controller method could then be simplified to this.

```
def show
  property = Property.find(params[:id])
  respond_with(property)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `respond_with` method takes two arguments: the `resources*`and a `&block` so you should be able to do this:

```
def show
  property = Property.find(params[:id])
  respond_with(property, :except => [:address1, 
                                     :address2, 
                                     :analysis_date, 
                                     :analysis_date_2, 
                                     ...])
end
```

And just remember, that in order to us `respond_with` properly you need to add `respond_to :html, :json, :xml` in the top of your controller. So that `respond_with`knows what mimes to respond to.